# VueJS client cannot communicate with NodeJs/Express backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, express, axios

I created a TodoList application to learn how to use NodeJS/Express/MongoDB/VueJS together.
(I followed this tutorial : https://signoz.io/blog/mevn-stack-tutorial/)

I use Axios as HTTP Client.

My problem is : when I run the server and the client, after a few seconds I got this error message :

```
ERROR
Request failed with status code 500
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500
    at settle (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:24:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:109:66)
```

The architecture of my project is the following (the main files/folders) :

```
.
--client
----vue.config.js
----src
------App.vue
--server
----index.js
--routes
----api
------todolist.js
--models
----todo.js
```

I have my front-end written with VueJs - App.vue (./client/src/):

```
<template>
    <div class="main">
        <h3>Todo List</h3>
        
        <form class="form">
            <input class="input" v-model="title" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter todo"/>
            <br />
            <input class="input" v-model="description" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Enter description" />
            <br />
            <button class="submit-button" @click="addTodo">Add Todo</button>
        </form>
        <div class="todo-container">
            <ul>
                <li v-for="(todo, i) in todos" v-bind:key="todo.id">
                    <div class="todo">
                        <span class="todo-name">{{todo.title}}</span>
                        <span class="todo-description">{{todo.description}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="delete-btn" @click="removeTodo(todo, i)">DELETE TODO</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from "axios";
    export default {
        name: 'App',
        data() {
            return {
                todos: [],
                description: "",
                title: "",
            };      
        },
        async mounted() {
            const response = await axios.get("api/todolist/");
            this.todos = response.data;
        },
        methods: {
            async addTodo(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                const response = await axios.post("api/todolist/", {
    title: this.title,
    description: this.description   
});
this.todos.push(response.data);
this.title = "";
this.description = "";
            },
            async removeTodo(item, i) {
                await axios.delete("api/todolist/"+item._id);
                this.todos.splice(i, 1);
            },
        }
};
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

I have some routes written in todolist.js (./routes/api/):

```
const {Router} = require('express')
const Todo = require('../../models/todo')

const router = Router()

router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const todoList = await Todo.find()
        if (!todoList) throw new Error('No Todo list found')
        res.status(200).json(todoList)
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message: error.message})
    }
})

router.post('/', async(req, res) => {
    const newTodo = new Todo(req.body)
    try {
        const todo = await newTodo.save()
        if(!todo) throw new Error('Something went wront saving the Todo')
        res.status(200).json(todo)
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message: error.message})
    }
})

router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const {id} = req.params
    try {
        const removed = await Todo.findByIdAndDelete(id)
        if(!removed) throw new Error('Something went wrong')
        res.status(200).json(removed)
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message: error.message})
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

My vue.config.js (in ./client/) :

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
    transpileDependencies: true,
    configureWebpack: {
        devServer: {
            proxy: {
                '/api': {
                    target: 'http://localhost:3000',
                },
            },
        },
    },
})
```

The backend server in index.js (./server/) :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const TodoListRoutes = require('../routes/api/todolist')
const path = require('path')
require('dotenv').config();


app.use(cors()) // Allow cross origin requests.
app.use(bodyParser.json()) // Convert the request into JSON.

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB database connected...'))
.catch((err) => console.log(err))

app.use('/api/todolist', TodoListRoutes)

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App is listening at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`)
})
```

My models in todo.js (./models/):

```
const {Schema, model} = require('mongoose')

const TodoSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
})

const Todo = model('todo', TodoSchema)

module.exports = Todo
```

Does someone has an hint about what is going wrong there?
I am a complete beginner with MEVN stack.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You probably should check the Network tab and see the response body of the request which returned a status of 500.

Comment: The blog you linked to has multiple errors in it and is badly written. You should `console.log(req.body)` inside `router.post('/'` to see if data was actually sent to the endpoint and parsed before the `new Todo` is executed.